# Can't install matplotlib using Python 3.6.0 a4-amd64

Tags: php, python-3.x, matplotlib, compiler-errors, pip

when downloading a pip using python 3.6, for example,

```
pip install matplotlib
```

using admin cmd prompt.

It keeps giving me error

```
code 1 "python setup.py egg_info" failed in error 1.
```

I have installed setup tools and have my wheels up-to-date.

What am I doing wrong or what do I need to do to resolve this problem?

Comment: please add the error logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no stable (working) version of matplotlib out there for python 3.6. But there is a release candidat with version number: 2.0.0rc2. You are able to install this version without any problem. Just specify this version on install:

```
pip install matplotlib==2.0.0rc2
```

If you have installed any other Version or if you want to upgrade lateron use the `-I` switch of pip like:

```
pip install -I matplotlib==2.0.0rc2
```

... to ignore the installed package and reinstall it instead.

If you try this later, [check](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/) the newest version and change it, to avoid an error.

Later on, if matplotlib is stable, the error sould be gone. But for now, this is the only working solution. The Problem in this case is not matplotlib itself, it is caused by the packages "png" and "Freetype".

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using pip for python3?
try with

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```